# Rspec: tests passing as white dots?

Tags: rspec

I have a few tests that are passing as white dots instead of the normal green. What do the white dots represent? or could this be due to a bug?

[image]

Edit: on further inspection, I believe this is related to a number of tests that are calling methods from `$stdin`, like `$stdin.gets` and `$stdin.stub`

Comment: Is anything else colored? What does running `echo $TERM` in your shell give you?

Comment: @jmdeldin yes, it is just normal xterm. I have updated the question.

Answer (score -1):

I had a string of white dots in the middle of my specs, just like yours. I was very confused for a few minutes. It turns out I had accidentally pressed and held down the period key for a second as the tests were running - thus a string of white periods.